# Make WPF ModernUI tab multiline

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs, modern-ui

I have a WPF user control which includes Modern UI tab. This is the xaml for the usercontrol (the modernui tab is at the end of the code):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Reports.Navigation_Reports"
             xmlns:Project="clr-namespace:Project" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"  
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             mui:ModernFrame.KeepAlive="False"
             d:DesignHeight="575" d:DesignWidth="750" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="sas" TargetType="mui:ModernTab">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="mui:ModernTab">
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- link list -->
                            <ListBox x:Name="LinkList" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Links}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="{DynamicResource HeaderMargin}"
                                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                 ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both">
                                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuText}" />
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                        <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Ideal" />
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuText}" />
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0,0,0" />
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuTextHover}"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuTextSelected}"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>

                            <!-- content -->
                            <mui:ModernFrame Source="{Binding SelectedSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" ContentLoader="{TemplateBinding ContentLoader}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="637" Margin="0,0,-270,-62">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="0" Width="1068" Height="627">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1031*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="37*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <mui:ModernTab Name="mTHome" Layout="Tab" SelectedSource="/Reports/LeadTasks/TabLeadTasks_Report.xaml" Margin="0,34,10,0" Height="464" VerticalAlignment= "Top" Style="{StaticResource sas}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                    <mui:Link x:Name="Report1" DisplayName="Report 1" Source="/Reports/Report1/TabReport1_Report.xaml"/>
                    <mui:Link x:Name="Report2" DisplayName="Report 2" Source="/Reports/Report2/TabReport2_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                    <mui:Link x:Name="Report3" DisplayName="Report 3" Source="/Reports/Report3/TabReport3_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                    <mui:Link x:Name="Report4" DisplayName="Report 4" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                </mui:ModernTab.Links>
            </mui:ModernTab>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

When I add more links, the tabs become invisible so I need to make it multiline, I searched the net about it but found nothing. There is no multiline or wrap property for this control. I tried to make it work through fixed width but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanelTemplate of the ListBox and get rid of the ScrollViewer as the ModernFrame already has one:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="sas" TargetType="{x:Type mui:ModernTab}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{DynamicResource HeaderMargin}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type mui:ModernTab}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ListBox x:Name="LinkList" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Links}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  
                                     ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                                   Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=mui:ModernTab}}"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, Converter={StaticResource ToUpperConverter}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuText}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                        <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Ideal"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuText}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0,0,0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuTextHover}"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuTextSelected}"/>
                                                        </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            </ListBox>
                            <mui:ModernFrame Grid.Row="1" ContentLoader="{TemplateBinding ContentLoader}" Source="{Binding SelectedSource, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1031*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="37*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <mui:ModernTab Name="mTHome" Layout="Tab" Margin="0,34,10,0" Height="464" VerticalAlignment= "Top" 
                       Style="{StaticResource sas}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                <mui:Link x:Name="Report1" DisplayName="Report 1" Source="/Reports/Report1/TabReport1_Report.xaml"/>
                <mui:Link x:Name="Report2" DisplayName="Report 2" Source="/Reports/Report2/TabReport2_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link x:Name="Report3" DisplayName="Report 3" Source="/Reports/Report3/TabReport3_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link x:Name="Report4" DisplayName="Report 4" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Report X" Source="/Reports/Report4/TabReport4_Report.xaml"></mui:Link>
            </mui:ModernTab.Links>
        </mui:ModernTab>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```